# What happen if the car charger don`t supply 1A, only 400 mA, if the device needs 1A?

Tags: safety, charger

I am trying to splice a cable (barrel port to a cigarette port). This is for a radio with 5V, 1A. In the package, there was a normal AC plug to barrel port. My plan is to just cut the cord and connect it to an old cellphone charger adapter. It is a really old charger, without any information on how many many amps it supplies. Since it is such an old charger it might only deliver a 400 mA. Can I safely test this out and if the radio work, can I assume that it worked flawlessly? Or do I have to check to overheating and stuff? (I do not have a multimeter)

Comment: Get a multimeter. And a car have 12volt not 5 volt. And 400mA vs 1A probably not, and perhaps if the volume is low.

Comment: @MatsK hes probably talking about a 12v-5v old cellphone charger adapter.

Comment: @tobiasht You need to look over your question, and edit it.

Comment: Pretty much all phone chargers for the car are 5V, even really old ones. I can therefore be quite certain that this one is as well. The only thing that seems to change, is the amount of Ampere the chargers deliver. I`m only wondering if it will be a problem if the radio pulls more power, then the charger is designed for (if it turns out that it`s only designed to deliver 400 mA.

Comment: You can expect failures to occur with shutdown under some conditions.

Comment: the radio likely won't mind, but the adapter could over heat, if it's not abnormally warm from 2/3 volume after 15 mins, i'd say it's fine. aside: since the charger is meant to charge a battery, i suspect it would push out at least 700ma like every phone charger i've seen...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't assume everything is ok even if the "radio" works.

- The old adapter may overheat and fail (dangerously or not).
- The "radio" could work on some conditions and perform wrong in others.